# MAUI: NotificationTapped event is not firing in foreground mode

Tags: maui

I am using `Plugin.Firebase` and `Plugin.Firebase.Crashlytics` packages for implementing push notification in my MAUI application. I referred [this](https://cedricgabrang.medium.com/firebase-push-notifications-in-net-maui-android-32c808844d7e) blog and it was working fine on the Android platform.

I have added the `NotificationTapped` event on the `App.xaml.cs` Constructor. This event is firing when the app is in `Background` or `Killed` modes. But the app is in foreground mode, this event is not firing. Below is my code:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CrossFirebaseCloudMessaging.Current.NotificationTapped += Current_NotificationTapped;
    }

    private void Current_NotificationTapped(object sender, FCMNotificationTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var data = e.Notification.Data;
            //reading data from notiifcatin and opening the page
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>>" + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Is anything else we need to do for firing this event on foreground mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to register the NotificationTapped event after the initialisation is completed? Or you can try just put it in the App.cs or MainPage constructor. Such as:

```
    public App()
    {
        CrossFirebaseCloudMessaging.Current.NotificationTapped += Current_NotificationTapped;
    }
```

> Is this tapping is enough for all the 3 modes? I mean background mode, foreground mode and killed mode?

According to this issue : [CloudMessaging: CrossFirebaseCloudMessaging.Current.NotificationTapped not invoked when app is killed](https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Plugin.Firebase/issues/59), it can work in all the 3 modes.

**Update:**

Add the `OnNewIntent` with `HandleIntent(intent)` function like below on `MainActivity` class for fixing the foreground mode tapping issue.

```
protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    base.OnNewIntent(intent);
    HandleIntent(intent);
}
```

https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Plugin.Firebase/issues/226

Comment: I tried putting the `NotificationTapped` event on `App.xaml.cs`, `MainPage` constructor and `MauiProgream.cs` classes. But the event is not firing when tapping the notification.

Comment: I found that this event is firing when the app is in background or killed mode. So far i tried it in foreground mode, in foreground mode the event is not firing.

Comment: Is anything else we need to do for firing this event on foreground mode?

Comment: I even tried in release mode, that time also `NotificationTapped` event is not firing.

Comment: Did you try the notification received event? It may be a bug. In addition, did you try the different versions of the firebase packages? @MatthewPans

Comment: I have updated the packages to latest, no luck. Also added the `NotificationReceived` and it is firing.

Comment: Using `NotificationReceived` event is it possible to do anything on tapping?

Comment: I have tried downgrading the `Plugin.Firebase` to lower versions like 2.0.6,2.0.5,2.0.4 and 2.0.3. But same issue on all versions. There are some errors when downgrading below 2.0.3. Is this a bug from that package?

Comment: I found the fix and added it on the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your update, and this seems appears in the first blog you mentioned. @MatthewPans

Comment: Hi @MatthewPans, please update the answer.

Comment: @SheikMydeenMuthu I have already updated it on the Answer. Please refer to this too: https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Plugin.Firebase/issues/226