# Plugin.FIrebase NotificationTapped event is not firing in foreground mode aftre upgrading to NET Maui 8

Tags: c#, android, maui

I'm using `Plugin.Firebase V2.0.12` for handling notifications in my Android app, when app is not in foreground mode it works as expected, but when in foreground the `NotificationTapped` event does not fire, I tried this [MAUI: NotificationTapped event is not firing in foreground mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77431936/maui-notificationtapped-event-is-not-firing-in-foreground-mode) but have not success.

Is worth mentioning that before updating my app to NET 8 (I was using NET 7 and `Plugin.Firebase V 2.0.5`) it was working fine

here are the relevants parts of my code.

`MauiProgram.cs`

```
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            // Initialize the .NET MAUI Community Toolkit by adding the below line of code
            .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
            .RegisterFirebaseServices()
            .UseSkiaSharp()           
            // After initializing the .NET MAUI Community Toolkit, optionally add additional fonts
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });

        // Continue initializing your .NET MAUI App here
    }

    private static MauiAppBuilder RegisterFirebaseServices(this MauiAppBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events => {
#if IOS
            events.AddiOS(iOS => iOS.FinishedLaunching((app, launchOptions) => {
                CrossFirebase.Initialize(CreateCrossFirebaseSettings());
                return false;
            }));
#else
            events.AddAndroid(android => android.OnCreate((activity, _) =>
                CrossFirebase.Initialize(activity, CreateCrossFirebaseSettings())));
#endif
        });

        //CrossFirebaseCrashlytics.Current.SetCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
        CrossFirebaseCloudMessaging.Current.TokenChanged += Current_TokenChanged;
        CrossFirebaseCloudMessaging.Current.NotificationReceived += Current_NotificationReceived;
        CrossFirebaseCloudMessaging.Current.NotificationTapped += Current_NotificationTapped;
        builder.Services.AddSingleton(_ => CrossFirebaseAuth.Current);
        return builder;
    }

    private static CrossFirebaseSettings CreateCrossFirebaseSettings()
    {
        return new CrossFirebaseSettings(isAuthEnabled: true, isCloudMessagingEnabled: true, isAnalyticsEnabled: false);
    }

    private static async void Current_NotificationTapped(object sender, Plugin.Firebase.CloudMessaging.EventArgs.FCMNotificationTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        var data = e.Notification.Data;
        var notification = new UnoNotification();
        foreach (var valuepair in data)
        {
            NotificationHelper.AssignFields(notification, valuepair.Key, valuepair.Value);

        }
        notification.ReceivedDate = notification.OrigenDate = DateTime.Now;
        if (notification.NotificationPushId <= 0) return;
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"///{nameof(OrganizationsPage)}/{nameof(NotificationDetailPage)}", true,
           new Dictionary<string, object>
           {
                   {"Notification",notification },
                   {"FromNotification",true }
           });
    }

    private static void Current_NotificationReceived(object sender, Plugin.Firebase.CloudMessaging.EventArgs.FCMNotificationReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var notification = e.Notification;
        var data = e.Notification.Data;

#if ANDROID
        FirebaseCloudMessagingImplementation.ChannelId = "nedchat_notification_channel";
        FirebaseCloudMessagingImplementation.NotificationBuilderProvider = MainActivity.CreateNotificationBuilder;
#endif

    }


    private static void Current_TokenChanged(object sender, Plugin.Firebase.CloudMessaging.EventArgs.FCMTokenChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var current = AppPreferencesHelper.GetFirebaseToken();
        var token = e.Token;
        if (current == token) return;
        AppPreferencesHelper.SetFirebaseToken(token);
        AppPreferencesHelper.SetIsFirebaseTokenPendingUpdate(true);
    }
```

I also tried putting the events in `App.xaml.cs` but the result is the same

`MainActivity.cs` under Platforms/Android

```
protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    UserDialogs.Init(this);
    _context = this;
    await HandleIntent(Intent);
    CreateNotificationChannelIfNeeded();
}

 protected override async void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
 {
     base.OnNewIntent(intent);
     await HandleIntent(intent);
 }

 private static async Task HandleIntent(Intent intent)
 {
     FirebaseCloudMessagingImplementation.OnNewIntent(intent);
     if (intent?.Extras == null) return;
     var notification = new UnoNotification();
     foreach (var key in intent.Extras.KeySet())
     {
         var value = intent.Extras.Get(key).ToString();

         NotificationHelper.AssignFields(notification, key, value);

     }
     notification.ReceivedDate = notification.OrigenDate = DateTime.Now;
     if (notification.NotificationPushId <= 0) return;

     intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
     intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);

     await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"///{nameof(OrganizationsPage)}/{nameof(NotificationDetailPage)}", true,
        new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
                {"Notification",notification },
                {"FromNotification",true }
        });
 }
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: this sounds like an issue with the Plugin.Firebase library. Your implementation looks fine. Just post an issue on the git repo, and somebody over there will take a look. Most likely something has changed in MAUI 8 that breaks the dependency, so either nobody has documented on the Firebase library what changes you need to make for it to work, or microsoft does what it always does...break everything, and not bother telling anyone about it

Answer (score 0):

So I Just deleted and redownloaded the project from my git repo, uninstalled and then reinstalled the app on the Android Phone and now it works just fine